# Jquery radiobox check event popup show

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I have trouble with jquery mobile radiobox checkbox showing popup.

I found this jquery code from jquery offical website:

```
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form>
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Please sign in</h3>
            <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a">
            <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my radio group html code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Üyelik Durumu</legend>
    <input id="radioPeryonUyesiyim" type="radio" name="radioPeryonUyelik" value="1" />
       <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop"></a>
    <label for="radioPeryonUyesiyim">PERYÖN ÜYESİYİM</label>
    <input id="radioPeryonUyeDegilim" type="radio" name="radioPeryonUyelik" value="0" />
    <label for="radioPeryonUyeDegilim">PERYON ÜYESİ DEĞİLİM</label>
</fieldset>
```

I want to check "radioPeryonUyesiyim" and login popup show. How can I do that?

I've searched the internet but i didn't solve it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And where is your jQuery code dude ?

Answer (score 0):

put this in your "head" tag:

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>      
  <script>
    function clickMe() {
        $("#popupLogin").show();
    }

</script>
```

Also call the clickMe() function on your input onclick event:

```
  <input id="radioPeryonUyesiyim" type="radio" name="radioPeryonUyelik" value="1" onclick="clickMe();" />
```

Hope this wil work for you.